# How to make the actionbar hide and show when we touch the screen?

Tags: android

My question was when we touch or scrolling the webview, the actionbar will show and then it will hide by itself in a period of time like 3 seconds

Comment: you want to hide action bar ? and rehide it?

Comment: do you created a actionbar?

Comment: Not created the actionbar. it was like the actionbar was showing but when we do one touch on screen it hide and then if we do one more touch it will show.

Comment: can you share your layout.xml

Comment: @Beginner have you tried my answer?? try this inside of your parent layout click event/touch

Comment: @Lokesh I think there is no actionbar, if Beginner share his layout.xml we understand.

Answer (score 3):

inside your touch event do like this:

```
if(getActionBar().isShowing()){
        getActionBar().hide();
    }else{
        getActionBar().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be shown whenever you are scrolling up and hide when scrolling down you can use touch gestures, please see here for a complete explanation https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html